# how to make JSON string with specified field in spring

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I have an object like this, and I have set for a field

```
installasimodel test = new installasimodel();
        test.setMid(js.getMid());
        test.setTid(js.getTid());
        test.setSts(js.getSts());
        test.setTtd(imgstr);
```

this my model

```
......
@Column(name="mid")
    private String mid;

    @Id
    @Column(name="tid")
    private Integer tid;

    @Column(name="sts")
    private int sts;

    @Column(name="ttd")
    private String ttd;

    @Column(name="version")
    private String version;
........get/set........
```

I want to make the end result like this

```
{"mid":"1212","tid":1111,"sts":2,"ttd":"ok"}
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
   <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
   <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Afterwards after etching your object, run the following code

```
installasimodel p = ...load a installasimodel ...;
JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
return serializer.serialize( p );
```

This would return what you've expected.

Links [FlexJson WebSite](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)